# How can I strip n bytes from each packet in a packet capture?

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I have a number of packet captures in pcap format. Each packet contains a message for which I have dissector however each packet has 4 bytes prepended to it. This means the dissector will not understand the format.

Is there anyway for me to mangle these captures such that they come out the other end with those 4 bytes stripped off?

Comment: Why don't you want to handle those four bytes? Are they part of a higher layer? If they are part of your protocol, you should handle them, even if they are just padding.

Comment: they're basically a header that is not part of the actual protocol, basically some packets go A->B->C where B prepends those 4 bytes and bridges A and C (who can't talk to each other). The dissector is not my code but it is open source. Basically I'm looking for a quick way to do this without getting into the dissector code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to edit at least one dissector to do what you want. The best thing to do is to write a dissector that will handle the header inserted by your B protocol, against which the C protocol dissector would need to register. This gives you the added benefit of being able to examine information in the header of the B protocol and filter on its fields.

However, if you really don't want to do that, you could modify either the A protocol or C protocol dissector to ignore those four bytes: in A, you would not include those bytes in the `tvb` given to C; or in C you would skip the first four bytes in the `tvb`.

Answer (score 0):

```
editcap.exe -L -C <num> <infile> <outfile>
```

Google: "man edicap"